# Connection to Mongodb fails from Strapi on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, strapi, heroku-cli

I deployed Strapi CMS to Heroku, but I get this error

**Error connecting to the Mongo database. Server selection timed out after 30000 ms**

Log:

```
2020-05-27T17:43:55.398256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-05-27T17:43:58.724121+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-27T17:43:58.724143+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi-oskogen-mongodb@0.1.0 start /app
2020-05-27T17:43:58.724143+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi start
2020-05-27T17:43:58.724143+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-27T17:44:02.234160+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T17:44:02.234179+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2020-05-27T17:44:02.234732+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T17:44:02.234879+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T17:44:02.235021+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T17:44:32.238852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-27T17:44:32.238Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-05-27T17:44:32.253150+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-27T17:44:32.253Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

My environments settings:

**database.js**

[image]

** server.js **

[image]

** response.js **

[image]

** config vars **

[image]

Site works well on localhost with both dev and prod environment. So it connects to MongoDB on Atlas and no problem with that.

I do not have any addons installed on Heroku.

** packages.json **

[image]

On Atlas side I opened all IPs in white list.

Any idea? Thank you! :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm currently experiencing the same problem and can't figure it out.

Comment: Try to change in Server.js ---> Port 443 made it work. module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 443),
});
I can give you my config if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no luck with this. Would appreciate if you could share your config as I'm super confused why this doesn't work. My config is all on [my own stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322925/strapi-heroku-deployment-fails-to-connect-to-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment110263317_62322925)

Comment: I have to go now. Is it ok I answer on week end? :)

Comment: Of course, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. Thanks very much and have a good day / weekend :)

Comment: Hi Fraserky, I have just published my answer. Hope it helps. ;-)

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My configuration for deployment of Strapi 3.0.1 on Heroku, both for develop and production environments:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "mongoose",
      settings: {
        uri: env("DATABASE_URI"),
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
      },
      options: {
        ssl: true,
        authenticationDatabase: "",
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        pool: {
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 443), <-- 443 was critical to make it work on production
});
```

.env - local file

```
DATABASE_URI="mongodb+srv://OdegXXXXXUser:OXXXX20@odXXXXcluster-h9o2e.mongodb.net/odeXXXXXndb?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
HOST="0.0.0.0"
PORT="1337"
```

Vars on Heroku:

[image]

DATABASE_URI er identical as on localhost, the same database.

I hope it will help to anybody :-)

Answer (score 0):

make this your database.json

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "${process.env.DATABASE_HOST}",
        "port": "${process.env.DATABASE_PORT}",
        "database": "${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}",
        "username": "${process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME}",
        "password": "${process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD}",
      },
      "options": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Also make sure to add package-lock.json to your git.ignore file. 
then do

```
git add .
git commit -m "(message) "
git push heroku master
```

then

`heroku open`
Start your app servers too